# Android Studio Arctic Fox - projects not building after update

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

After updating android studio to current latest (2020.3.1.24) I'm not able to open any file/class/document inside it, run or build the project. Creating new project, android studio generates only the files in the  [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qmIO.png), and I'm not able to open any of those. As you can see there is also no available run/debug configuration. I'm using 7.0.2 gradle plugin version, and jdk 11.

Answer (score 0):

Update your plugin and android studio to the last version.

these versions are stable now:

Gradle wrapper properties:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip
```

and build Gradle :

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.5.30' apply false
}
```